# wordpress navigation menu without sub menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I am using this code to display **navigation menu**:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
```

This code display navigation menu with sub-menu at header area. but I do't want to display sub-menu at footer area just display main menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu','depth' => 1) ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this line in CSS file

```
.footer_inner ul li ul{
display:none;
}
```

Its also according to my requirements.

But this Code is more better than above css code.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu','depth' => 1) ) ); ?>
```